# How to plot this DataFrame easier in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

This is my DataFrame:

[image: DataFrame]

I plotted my df in Pandas with this code:

```
Armenia = [100.0,   21.943089,  23.344123]
Moldova = [100.0, 25.468598, 25.856620]
Ukraine =   [100.0, 45.253380, 26.266646]

Vietnam =   [100.0, 491.680706, 1083.782579]
Oman =  [100.0, 277.381353, 659.887243]
Bangladesh =    [100, 280.025959, 609.648111]


df = pd.DataFrame({'Vietnam' : Vietnam, 'Ukraine' : Ukraine, 'Bangladesh' : Bangladesh, 'Oman' : Oman,'Armenia': Armenia,'Moldova': Moldova}, index = ['1990', '2005', '2017'])

ax = df.plot.line(rot=0)

plt.title('Top 3 best and worst countries in combatting CO2 emission above 5 mt CO2', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('years', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('relative amount of CO2 emitted in %', fontsize=12)
plt.grid(True)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Is there any easier way to do this? Because it takes a lot of time to write all the data.

I really appreciate any comments. Thanks! :)

Comment: _it takes a lot of time to write all the data_ can you clarify this?

Comment: Well, because for now it's just 6 countries with 3 datapoints but imagine if this would have 20 countries with 10 datapoints. There must be a more generic way to this.. i'm new to pandas and python btw.

Comment: So your problem isn't ploting but writing the data, from where you get that data?

Comment: are you asking about potting the dataframe or creating the dataframe?

Comment: From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_carbon_dioxide_emissions

but I've filtered, sorted and selected it into my own DataFrame as shown above

Comment: @PaulH I'm asking how to plot the DataFrame easier into a line chart without using all these information below I've written myself:

Armenia = [100.0,   21.943089,  23.344123]
Moldova = [100.0, 25.468598, 25.856620]
Ukraine =   [100.0, 45.253380, 26.266646]

Vietnam =   [100.0, 491.680706, 1083.782579]
Oman =  [100.0, 277.381353, 659.887243]
Bangladesh =    [100, 280.025959, 609.648111]

Comment: so you're asking about creating the dataframe. the plot command is the same no matter how many rows or columns you have

Comment: I would copy/paste that data into an excel file and use `pandas.read_excel`

Comment: @PaulH thanks, I'm going to try it out and hopefully it will work. I keep you updated

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframe is in wide format so I changed it to long format using `pd.melt` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html))

I plotted the measurements using barplots since I thought you could see the evolution of CO2 emissions better like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

dic = {'country' : ['Vietnam', 'Oman', 'Bangladesh', 'Ukraine', 'Moldova', 'Armenia'],
       'base' : [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0],
       'RA05' : [491, 277, 280, 45, 25, 21],
       'RA17' : [1083, 659, 609, 26, 25, 23]
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df_melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars='country', value_name='Value', var_name='Measurement')
print(df_melted)
```

[image: melted]

*Barplot* version in Seaborn:

```
ax = sns.barplot(data=df_melted, x='country', y='Value', hue='Measurement')
ax.set(xlabel='Country', ylabel='Relative amount of CO2 emitted in %', title='Top 3 best and worst countries in combatting CO2 emission above 5 mt CO2')
plt.show()
```

[image: barplot]

*Lineplot* version in seaborn:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df_melted, x='Measurement', y='Value', hue='country')
ax.set(xlabel='Year', ylabel='Relative amount of CO2 emitted in %', title='Top 3 best and worst countries in combatting CO2 emission above 5 mt CO2')
plt.show()
```

[image: lineplot]

*Lineplot* attempt in pandas.

```
df_melted.groupby('country')['Value'].plot(legend=True, marker='x', linestyle='--', 
                                           title='Top 3 best and worst countries in combatting CO2 emission above 5 mt CO2', 
                                           xticks=[], xlabel='years', ylabel='Relative amount of CO2 emitted in %')
```

[image]